# Why $cd(a^2+b^2)+ab(c^2+d^2)= (ad+bc)(ac+bd)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we simplify $cd(a^2+b^2)+ab(c^2+d^2)$ to $(ad+bc)(ac+bd)$. I see that they're equivalent, but how someone comes up with this?

Comment: @AdamRubinson, that being helpful how? Your comment is even being upvoted and then we are talking about the quality of the questions here.

Comment: We can and must simplify this by opening the brackets on both sides. That's just how it is done. Coming up with ***ideas*** like this is on an entirely another level of difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sometimes helpful to expand and work backwards. The idea is mostly just a clever way of grouping terms:

$$(ad + bc)(ac + bd) = ad(ac + bd) + bc(ac + bd) = (\color{red}{a^2dc} + \color{red}{abd^2}) + (\color{blue}{abc^2} + \color{blue}{b^2cd}) = (\color{red}{a^2dc} + \color{blue}{b^2cd}) + (\color{red}{abd^2} + \color{blue}{abc^2}) = cd(a^2 + b^2) + ab(d^2 + c^2).$$